# How to center image in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an image svg element, which can have whatever width. I want to center the image horizontally in svg element or div container. I tried `margin: 0 auto;` or `text-align : center;` but it doesn't work.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjne9eyz/)

**html**

```
<div class="background-img" style="width: 100px; height: 110px;">
   <svg class="svg-defs" width="100px" height="110px">
      <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip-triangle-10">
            <polygon points="0,0 110,0 110,100 19,100 12,107 5,100 0,100 0,0"></polygon>
         </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <rect class="svg-background" clip-path="url(#clip-triangle-10)" width="100px" height="110px"></rect>
      <image class="svg-image" clip-path="url(#clip-triangle-10)" height="100px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6c/Seafarers_title.jpg/225px-Seafarers_title.jpg"></image>
   </svg>
</div>
```

```css
image{
 position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-img" style="width: 100px; height: 110px;">
   <svg class="svg-defs" width="100px" height="110px">
      <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip-triangle-10">
            <polygon points="0,0 110,0 110,100 19,100 12,107 5,100 0,100 0,0"></polygon>
         </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <rect class="svg-background" clip-path="url(#clip-triangle-10)" width="100px" height="110px"></rect>
      <image class="svg-image" clip-path="url(#clip-triangle-10)" height="100px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6c/Seafarers_title.jpg/225px-Seafarers_title.jpg"></image>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible via just HTML and CSS with the width of the image coming from the external image. If you're willing to use some JavaScript then this might be a possible solution:

```
var svgImage = document.querySelectorAll('.svg-image');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(svgImage, function(el, i){
  var xOffset = '-' + ((Math.floor(el.getBoundingClientRect().width)) - 100) / 2
  el.setAttribute('x', xOffset);
});
```

This loops over every `.svg-image` and then calculates the offset needed to center the image in the 100px wide display.

It can be seen in action on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjne9eyz/5/)

Comment: I wanted to avoid this solution, but maybe there is no other way. I will let this question opened for 1-2 days. If there is no other solution, I will accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: I can't think of another way. Purely because the image size is likely to vary and will need calculating for each individual one.

Answer (score 1):

```css
   image{
 position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align : center;   
}
```

```html
<div class="background-img" style="width: 100px; height: 110px;">
   <svg class="svg-defs" width="100px" height="110px">
      <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip-triangle-10">
            <polygon points="0,0 110,0 110,100 19,100 12,107 5,100 0,100 0,0"></polygon>
         </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <rect class="svg-background" clip-path="url(#clip-triangle-10)" width="100px" height="110px"></rect>
      <image class="svg-image" x="-15px" clip-path="url(#clip-triangle-10)" height="100px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6c/Seafarers_title.jpg/225px-Seafarers_title.jpg"></image>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read my question again: _"image svg element, which can have whatever width_". This solution works just for this image, not image with various width

Comment: each image is different  and each one you need to start from another pixel, sorry i dont know the answer

Comment: So, there is no generic solution for that?

Comment: @Matt check my solution it will work with svg of any width in the container.

Comment: i dont think so , you can take couple pictures and think about common factor and try to work with that

Comment: @iamwtk you centered the container, not the image

Comment: @Matt I centered SVG inside div container

Comment: @NofarEliasi maybe you are right and it is the only how to center the image. I will let open this question, just in case someone has answer for that.

Answer (score -2):

Hi just add `margin: 0 auto to your` background-img block

https://jsfiddle.net/mjne9eyz/3/

Comment: I need to center image, not image container

Comment: SVG is inline by default. Add display: block to it and then margin: auto will work as expected.

Comment: Your both jsfiddle are the some, you centered the container, not image

Comment: hmm https://jsfiddle.net/mjne9eyz/4/ svg{display: block; margin: 0 auto;}

i'm sure a centered svg )

Comment: I remove width from container and he is 100% width, than i add display:block to svg, and centered it